# Linq to SQL - Joins and Skip+Take

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have Linq-to-SQL code that works with a many-to-many relationship, but note that the relationship itself has its own set of attributes (in this case, Products are in Many Categories, and each product-in-category relation has its own SortOrder attribute).

I have a Linq-to-SQL block that returns matching Products with Category membership information. When I execute the code it generates optimised T-SQL code like so:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[ProductId], [t0].[Name], [t1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId2], [t1].[CategoryId], [t1].[SortOrder] AS [SortOrder2], [t2].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId2], [t2].[Name] AS [Name2] (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[ProductsInCategories] AS [t3]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Categories] AS [t4] ON [t4].[CategoryId] = [t3].[CategoryId]
WHERE [t3].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId]
) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN ([dbo].[ProductsInCategories] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Categories] AS [t2] ON [t2].[CategoryId] = [t1].[CategoryId]) ON [t1].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId]
WHERE (([t0].[OwnerId]) = @p0) AND ([t0].[Visible] = 1)
ORDER BY [t0].[SortOrder], [t0].[Name], [t0].[ProductId], [t1].[CategoryId]',N'@p0 bigint',@p0=3
```

However, when I add paging instructions (i.e.".Skip(0).Take(50)") to the Linq expression the generated SQL becomes this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (50) [t0].[ProductId], [t0].[Name]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [t0]
WHERE (([t0].[OwnerId]) = @p0) AND ([t0].[Visible] = 1)
ORDER BY [t0].[SortOrder], [t0].[Name]',N'@p0 bigint',@p0=3
```

Which means the Category membership information isn't loaded anymore, so Linq-to-SQL then executes the manual loading code 50 times over (one for each member in the returned set):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[ProductId], [t0].[CategoryId], [t0].[SortOrder], [t1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId2], [t1].[Name]
FROM [dbo].[ProductsInCategories] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Categories] AS [t1] ON [t1].[CategoryId] = [t0].[CategoryId]
WHERE [t0].[ProductId] = @x1',N'@x1 bigint',@x1=1141
```

(obviously the "@x1" ID parameter varies for each result from the original query).

So clearly Linq paging breaks the query and causes it to load data separately. Is there a way around this or should I do paging in my own software?

...fortunately the number of products in the database is small enough (<500) to do this, but it just feels dirty because there **could** be tens of thousands of products, and this just wouldn't be a good query.

EDIT:

Here is my Linq:

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Product>( p => p.ProductsInCategories );
dlo.LoadWith<ProductsInCategory>( pic => pic.Category );
this.LoadOptions = dlo;

query = from p in this.Products
select p;

// The lines below are added conditionally:
query = query.OrderBy( p => p.SortOrder ).ThenBy( p => p.Name );
query = query.Where( p => p.Visible );
query = query.Where( p => p.Name.Contains( filter ) || p.Description.Contains( filter ) );
query = query.Where( p => p.OwnerId == siteId );
```

The skip/take lines are added optionally, and are the only differences that cause the different T-SQL generation (as far as I know):

```
IQueryable<Product> query = GetProducts( siteId, category, filter, showHidden, sortBySortOrder );

///////////////////////////////////

total = query.Count();

var pagedProducts = query.Skip( pageIndex * pageSize ).Take( pageSize );
return pagedProducts;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer which first pages the products and then selects products and categories in a parent-child structure would be like this:

```
var filter = "a";
var pageSize = 2;
var pageIndex = 1;

// get the correct products
var query = Products.AsQueryable();

query = query.Where (q => q.Name.Contains(filter));
query = query.OrderBy (q => q.SortOrder).ThenBy(q => q.Name);

// do paging
query = query.Skip(pageSize*pageIndex).Take(pageSize);

// now get products + categories as tree structure
var query2 = query.Select(
    q=>new 
    {
        q.Name, 
        Categories=q.ProductsInCategories.Select (pic => pic.Category)
    });
```

Which produces a single SQL statement

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = '%a%'
DECLARE @p1 Int = 2
DECLARE @p2 Int = 2
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t2].[Name], [t4].[CategoryId], [t4].[Name] AS [Name2], [t4].[Visible], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT [t5].[CategoryId]
        FROM [ProductsInCategories] AS [t5]
        WHERE [t5].[ProductId] = [t2].[ProductId]
        ) AS [t6]
    INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [t7] ON [t7].[CategoryId] = [t6].[CategoryId]
    ) AS [value]
FROM (
    SELECT [t1].[ProductId], [t1].[Name], [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[SortOrder], [t0].[Name], [t0].[ProductId]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[ProductId], [t0].[Name]
        FROM [Products] AS [t0]
        WHERE [t0].[Name] LIKE @p0
        ) AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p1 + 1 AND @p1 + @p2
    ) AS [t2]
LEFT OUTER JOIN ([ProductsInCategories] AS [t3]
    INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [t4] ON [t4].[CategoryId] = [t3].[CategoryId]) ON [t3].[ProductId] = [t2].[ProductId]
ORDER BY [t2].[ROW_NUMBER], [t3].[CategoryId], [t3].[ProductId]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround: you should construct your query based on all your conditions, perform ordering there but select only the primary key on your `Product` table (let's assume this is `ProductId` column).

The next step is to take the total count (to calculate rows should be skipped and taken), 
and the last step is to select all the records from your `Product` table whose `ProductId`s are in the `query` (note: `Skip` and `Take` extension methods should be applied to `query`, not to the new select itself).

This will get you a `SELECT` statement similar to yours (from the first example) with related entities.

**EDIT**:
Just created a similar DB structure (according to the original SQL from the question):

[image: DB structure]

Then used:

```
using (var db = new TestDataContext())
{
    DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<Product>(p => p.ProductsInCategories);
    options.LoadWith<ProductsInCategory>(pic => pic.Category);
    db.LoadOptions = options;

    var filter = "product";
    var pageIndex = 1;
    var pageSize = 10;

    var query = db.Products
        .OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder)
        .ThenBy(p => p.Name)
        .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(filter) || p.Description.Contains(filter))
        .Select(p => p.ProductId);

    var total = query.Count();

    var products = db.Products
        .Where(p => query.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).Contains(p.ProductId))
        .ToList();
}
```

After the `.ToList()` call, `products` variable hold products with product categories with categories. This also produced 2 SQL statement, one - for `.Count()` statement:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Name] LIKE @p0) OR ([t0].[Description] LIKE @p1)',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'%product%',@p1=N'%product%'
```

and another one for `.ToList()`:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[ProductId], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Description], [t0].[SortOrder], [t1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId2], [t1].[CategoryId], [t1].[SortOrder] AS [SortOrder2], [t2].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId2], [t2].[Name] AS [Name2], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [dbo].[ProductsInCategories] AS [t6]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [t7] ON [t7].[CategoryId] = [t6].[CategoryId]
        WHERE [t6].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId]
        ) AS [t8]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN ([dbo].[ProductsInCategories] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [t2] ON [t2].[CategoryId] = [t1].[CategoryId]) ON [t1].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId]
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t4].[ProductId]
        FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t3].[SortOrder], [t3].[Name], [t3].[ProductId]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t3].[ProductId]
            FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [t3]
            WHERE ([t3].[Name] LIKE @p0) OR ([t3].[Description] LIKE @p1)
            ) AS [t4]
        WHERE [t4].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p2 + 1 AND @p2 + @p3
        ) AS [t5]
    WHERE [t5].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId]
    )
ORDER BY [t0].[ProductId], [t1].[CategoryId]',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 int,@p3 int',@p0=N'%product%',@p1=N'%product%',@p2=10,@p3=10
```

No more extra queries (as SQL Server Profiler said).

Comment: DataLoadOptions is set to load ProductCategories and Categories, for each product. This produces those 50 extra queries. How do we get rid of them and still get get the ProductCategories and Categories?

Comment: @Adrian, no. This solution uses one query(honestly, another one for `Count`) for all products and should still get `ProductCategories` and `Categories` related to `Product`. The database I used for testing purposes has the similar structure `Article` - `ArticleTag` - `Tag`. I used similar approach there, and get all the related entities in one query.